# change properties of an element by a button from included document

Tags: php, jquery

I am just starting with PHP. What i am trying to get to do is change the color of a div from a function that's in an included page. I was able to do this in jquery using load() function.
Here is my current work:
index.php:

```
    include 'functioncontainer.php';
    <div style="background-color:#ffff00;">I want this back. color changed</div>
```

functioncontainer.php:

```
    `<script>
    $(document).load(function() {
    $('.change').click(function() {
    $('div').css('background-color','#06C');
    });
    });
    </script>`
```

Comment: don't worry about formats, i'm 100% sure they're fine.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: why these ``` try echo `' code'`

Comment: First of all you can't have HTML tags without quotes in PHP code.

Comment: Include the javascript code in the main page.Also use $(document).ready(function()... instead of $(document).load(function()

Comment: i cant use the code in the main page. The function needs to be in other page

Answer (score 0):

I don't know php but I think you need to `echo`

```
echo "<script>
    $(document).load(function() {
    $('.change').click(function() {
    $('div').css('background-color','#06C');
    });
    });
    </script>";
```